# Fetching values from second table in the Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
select * 
from EFLOVRelationship R 
where R.parentEFLOVValueId = '5320' 
  and R.childEFLOVId in (select Eflovid 
                         from EFFieldLOVStaticValue  
                         where efLovId = 49)
```

In the above query I want to fetch 2 columns from `EFFieldLOVStaticValue` table and display.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Use `join`:

```
select R.*, sv.?, sv.?
from EFLOVRelationship R join
     EFFieldLOVStaticValue sv
     ON sv.Eflovid = R.childEFLOVId and sv.efLovId = 49
where R.parentEFLOVValueId = '5320'
```

Comment: By using my query i got only one record,but if i use the above query i am getting 2k records.

Comment: I want to fetch only one record and want to get fields from the second table

Answer (score 0):

Use `Inner Join`

```
SELECT R.*, 
       V.field1, 
       V.field2 
FROM   eflovrelationship R 
       INNER JOIN effieldlovstaticvalue V 
               ON R.childeflovid = V.eflovid 
WHERE  R.parenteflovvalueid = '5320' 
       AND V.eflovid = 49
```

If your table has `1:N` relationship then use `Distinct` to avoid duplicates in result

If you want just one record from `effieldlovstaticvalue` table for each `R.childeflovid` column then use `Cross Apply` but you need to use required column to order the result and choose the top 1 record

```
SELECT R.*, 
       CS.field1, 
       CS.field2 
FROM   eflovrelationship R 
       CROSS apply (SELECT TOP 1 field1, 
                                 field2 
                    FROM   effieldlovstaticvalue V 
                    WHERE  R.childeflovid = V.eflovid 
                           AND eflovid = 49 
                    ORDER  BY someordercolumn) CS 
WHERE  R.parenteflovvalueid = '5320'
```

Comment: SELECT  distinct R.*, 
       V.valuePropertyName, 
       V.efLovValueId
FROM   eflovrelationship R 
       INNER JOIN effieldlovstaticvalue V 
               ON R.childeflovid = V.eflovid 
WHERE  R.parenteflovvalueid = '5320' 
       AND V.eflovid = 49

Comment: This also gave me 2k results but using my query i got only one result

Comment: @user2102115 - That means for a single record in `childeflovid` has more than one record in `eflovid` column in `effieldlovstaticvalue` table

Comment: So now using my query is there any other way to fetch values from the second table

Comment: @user2102115 Try using `Distinct`..  post sample data and expected result.

Comment: @user2102115 - Added another method